# How do i link search result with HTML page in PHP

Tags: php

Below is the code that i have written that would display data from phpmyadmin table and display the result. Now once the search result is displayed, let's say if i wish to click on one of the search result for e.g. i clicked on "Jon Doe" then upon click i should be redirected to the profile page (HTML page) of Jon Doe. May i know how do i do that ?

```html
<?php
 echo "<body style='background-color:gray'>";
include ("account.php");
( $dbh = mysql_connect( $hostname, $username, $password ))
    or die ( "uable to connect to MYSQL database" );
mysql_select_db( $project );


if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $sql= "SELECT * FROM registration ";

    $search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_box']);

    $sql .= "WHERE first_name= '{$search_term}'";

    $sql .= " OR last_name= '{$search_term}'";
    $query=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}



?>



<html>  
<head>  
<title>jon</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
<form name="search_form" method="POST" action="retrieve.php">  
<table width="599" border="1">  
<tr>  
<th>Search

<input type ="text" name ="search_box" value=""/>
<input type="submit" name="search" value="Find Users">

</tr>  
</table>  
</form>  


<table width="600" border="1">  
<tr>  
<th width="91"> <div align="center">First Name </div></th>  
<th width="98"> <div align="center">Last Name </div></th>  
<th width="198"> <div align="center">Email </div></th>  
<th width="97"> <div align="center">City </div></th>  
<th width="59"> <div align="center">Country </div></th>     

<tr>


<?php  if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){ ?>


<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['first_name'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['last_name'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['email'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['address_city'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['address_country'];?></td>



<tr>

<?php }} ?>

</table>
```

Comment: You have to create a page (for example profile.php) that can accept a variable http://yoursite/profile.php?userid=(whatever the id # of the user you want to show)

Comment: Is it possible u can show me some example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Funk Doc already suggested you should make a "profile.php" for example which then queries all informations.

First you need to link the profile page. You need a "id" from your database.

```
 <td><a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['first_name'];?></a></td>
```

Now you will redirect your user to profile.php with a special id.

**example: profile.php?id=87341**

In your profile.php you now need to get the id variable.

**profile.php**

```
<?php
$userid = $_GET['id'];
?>
```

The id is now saved in ´$userid´. Just search your database for that id and you get all your informations.

Comment: Awesome this is what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Ok lets say you have 2 Users John and Nick. John has id=1 and Nick id=2

```
<a href="handler.php?id=1">John</a>
<a href="handler.php?id=2">Nick</a>
```

**handler.php**

```
<?php
$id=$_GET['id'];
$query='SELECT * FROM #__users where id='.$id;
//show your results

?>
```